# Find a node with most connections to other unique nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Given:

- Two node labels:

  - 1000 `(:A)` nodes
  - 1000 `(:B)` nodes
- Constraints:

  - `CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (a:A) ASSERT a.id IS UNIQUE;`
  - `CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (b:B) ASSERT b.id IS UNIQUE;`
- One unidirectional relationship type:

  - 4000 `[:RELATED_TO]` relationships
- Multiple `(a:A)-[:RELATED_TO]->(b:B)` paths
  (Meaning, the same node `(a:A)` could be related to the same node `(b:B)` multiple times)

I'm trying to run a query that would show the paths of the node that is connected to the biggest number of other unique nodes in the graph. For example, if nodes `(a1:A)`, `(a2:A)`, `(a3:A)`, and `(a4:A)` are all connected to `(b:B)` at least once, and it so happens that no other `(:B)` is connected to any more than three unique `(:A)` nodes elsewhere in the graph, I would like for the Neo4j Browser to show `(b:B)` in the center and `(a1:A)` through `(a4:A)` around it. I feel like my biggest challenge is that I haven't been able to figure out how to avoid counting up multiple `(a1:A)-[:RELATED_TO]->(b:B)` paths.

I'll be happy to provide more context if necessary. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query uses the [aggregating function](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/functions/aggregating/) `COLLECT` (with the `DISTINCT` operator to qualify its argument) to return the `B` node that has relationships with the most distinct `A` nodes, along with those `A` nodes:

```
MATCH (a:A)-[:RELATED_TO]->(b:B)
RETURN b, COLLECT(DISTINCT a) AS aNodes
ORDER BY SIZE(aNodes) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```